# How do you encourage end users to fill out trouble tickets?

Tags: end-user, bug-reporting, trouble-tickets

So, I work in a fairly small IT section.  We have a trouble ticketing system that about half of our end users use.  Some of my coworkers don't really do much to encourage our end users to use the system we have in place.  The end result?  Constant interruptions because end users will get us by IM or come to our offices directly for trivial things.  This can obviously make it difficult to do a good job of writing code.

Now, I suppose I could just say "hey, would you mind filling out a trouble ticket next time?", but then I'd come off as the bad guy because others won't do that.  I also don't want end users to feel that I'm unapproachable.  I just want them to understand that there's a proper way to ask for help.

So what's the best thing for me to do in a situation like this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Make it appealing to do so.**

Mention to the user that issues with trouble tickets are viewed by the entire development team and have been found to  get fixed significantly faster.  Say that anything without a ticket has the potential to get lost in the shuffle. Provide them outward facing links so they can view the progress and developer/support comments on their ticket.  Provide email alerts so they feel like they are part of the process and have instant information about their issue.

**Make it as frictionless as possible.**

Make the user entry part of the system as easy to use and as intuitive as possible.  No one likes filling out tickets and I'm *certainly* not going to jump through any hoops to do so.  No logins, no sign-ins, just type out my issue and contact information and go.

**Talk with your team.**

Ultimately, no amount of hard work on the above systems is going to matter unless your team and you are on the same page.  Call for a team meeting and talk with them about the issue.  With your boss present, try and put it in terms he can understand.  Mention valuable time lost, issues tracking customer problems which aren't in the system, etc, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like your manager is letting you down by not forcing users to submit a ticket before getting help.  The problem starts there and only continues to your co-workers allowing such behavior.  We use redmine at work for application support and have made good progress in telling users "submit a ticket and we will look in to it" but it has to be a consistent voice from all people involved.

Answer (score 5):

Use a little psychology on them. For people that don't send in trouble tickets, remind them that 80% of the people in their department use the ticketing system. Even if it is a lie, it will encourage good behavior because of the bandwagon effect. Remember that the more similar the person is to demographic statistic, the more likely it is to influence their behavior. So "your immediate coworkers" will work better than "people in this entire company."

The people that use the ticketing system should get a gold star, no, seriously.

There was a very brief article in February's Harvard Business Review on using social pressure to influence behavior. It discussed some new research but the article didn't include references.

Answer (score 3):

You don't. Users hate that stuff even I do. Instead your policy should be "don't make me think". You have to collect all you need yourself and automatically handle this in an invisible way to your users. After they opt in at install.

Answer (score 2):

You probably won't make much headway unless you convince your coworkers to use the system first.  After you've all agreed on the process you want, then you can talk to your users.  If everyone on your team is playing by the same rules, you can probably force your users to use the system by having slow turn-around times for issues not entered into the system, or maybe even forget them altogether.

However, even IF you can convince both your coworkers and your users to enter tickets, you'll probably still find the tickets are incomplete/not informative.  We've all seen plenty of tickets like "Feature X is broken, fix it plz" and offer no other information.  Depending on the number of tickets you get per day, I would probably just bite the bullet and walk over the user and see what their problem is first hand.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily bother me to go by their desk to see the problem.  My main concern is with preventing interruption.

Comment: It's fine to walk over and ask, as long as there was an attempt at submitting a ticket.  That way you aren't viewed negatively because you do care, but you won't be allowing users to walk all over you.

Answer (score 2):

We often log a ticket on the user's behalf in this sort of case.

Answer (score 2):

At my old workplace, I was told that nothing could be done without a trouble ticket. When I asked why, I was told that the support team's productivity was measured by using trouble tickets. This had the effect of forcing me to use trouble tickets (since they were required), and giving me the motivation to do so (I didn't want my coworkers to look bad).

At my new workplace, all technical support is subcontracted out. I literally have to call tech support, and they create a ticket on my behalf.

Answer (score 1):

Also - stop encouraging the behavior. Use your IM filtering options to only appear online to the dev team. Don't check your email - or setup filters that filter the high priority stuff (your boss, your dev team) to your inbox, and everything else to a folder you check once a day or once every other day.

Answer (score 1):

Simucal's advice is good.  You -will- have to tell them to "file a ticket" instead, at some point.  If you ask them after the fact, they aren't going to care because they got what they needed.

A great way to handle this is to have a dedicated person for support.  My team did this, and it helped our productivity immensely and eliminated at least 90% of our interruptions.

Barring that (or lieu of), you can each rotate daily as to who gets to handle user requests.  This has the upshot of making a trouble ticket more-or-less required; its needed to keep track of what happened in the request when someone else starts working on it.  Over time, this also brings more cohesion to your processes: people create small scripts to do common tasks, work that is done is moved into revision control, etc.